# Many independent threads dependent on single thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a file which has n columns and many rows

```
    Col 1 col2 col3 .......col n
```

I want to read it once and write multiple (say m) outputs grouping the rows by few key columns. Say 3 outputs have to be produced:

For output 1:

```
groupingKeys[0]={1,2) //group the records on col 1 and 2
```

For output 2:

```
groupingKeys[1]={1,4,5} //group the records on col 1 4 5
```

For output 3

```
groupingKeys[2]={2,3}  //group on col 2,3
```

In Main-thread I read the input file line by line. For each read line I want to process the read line in m different threads. So basically I want that the calls

```
map[0].process(data,groupingKeys[0]);
map[1].process(data,groupingKeys[1]); 
map[2].process(data,groupingKeys[2]);
```

should run in 3 different threads and each of the 3 threads should proceed only after main thread has read the line.

I can create m different threads with run method of i-th thread having

```
map[i].process(data,groupingKeys[i]);
```

But these 3 threads should proceed only when main-thread which reads the line so that they see correct value of `data[]`. How can i achieve this?

```
    Main thread   thread-0     thread-1       thread-2
    running       waiting      waiting        waiting
    waiting       running      running        running
    running       waiting      waiting        waiting
```

**At each step a line is read and processed
By processed i mean something similar to sql groupby is done for each of the grouping keys** 
Below is the sample code referred above.

```
public void writeMultipleGroupedOutputs(String inputfile,int groupingKeys[][])
{
    Mymap<key,value>[] mapArr= new Mymap<key,value>[k]; //k maps to group records in k ways as per k grouping keys
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] data=line.split(regex);  **//one line is read in main thread**
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            map[i].process(data,groupingKeys[i]); **//process in m different ways.How to make this happen in m independent threads?**
    }

    class Mymap extends HashMap<key,value> {
        void  process(String[] data,int[] keyIndexes)
        {
            //extract key from key indexes
            //extract value from value indexes
            put(key,value);
        }  

        @Override
        public Value put(Key k, Value v) {
            if (containsKey(k)) {
                oldval=get(k);
                put(k,oldval.aggregate(v)); //put sum of old and new
                return oldval;
            }else{
                put(k,v);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if i haven't made my point clear.In simple words the i want   map[i].process(data,groupingKeys[i]); to happen in separate(i-th thread)

```
a b 5
a b 10
a c 15
so if i want to group by {1} and {1,2} 
read line        map1          map2
a b 5           [a--> b,5]      [a,b ->5]
a b 10          [a-> b 15]      [a,b->15]
a c 15          [a->b 30]       [a,b->15   a,c->15]
```

Edit:
The question is not related to how i process or the logic of grouping but it is that: **After each line is read i want to do something with the read line in different threads.**

Comment: This code doesn't compile and doesn't explain much.

Comment: Added some explaination.The code is just for reference and won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wish to wait with processing until all the file is read. If so, depending on the details, you may want to check out `CyclicBarrier` or `CountDownLatch`

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html